# Remove extra brackets with Gson and Volley

Tags: android, gson, android-volley

I'm doing a small App to check if the laptops in my university are available to loan, and I've been following most of the tutorials, like [this](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-json-parsing-using-gson-and-recyclerview/) and [this](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/tutorial-parsing-json-on-android-using-gson-and-volley).

Unfortunately the webpage I'm trying to get the data from (that I can't edit) **gives me the data with extra brackets** like this and doesn't work by default with [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). (clear text traffic).

```
[
  [
    {
      "z36_rec_key": "000043057000060",
      "z36_id": "16356332    ",
      "z36_due_date": 20171221,
      "z36_due_hour": 1159,
      "status": "Unavailable"
    },
    {
      "z36_rec_key": "none",
      "z36_id": "none",
      "z36_due_date": 0,
      "z36_due_hour": 0,
      "status": "Available"
    }
  ]
]
```

Is there a way to remove the first pair of brackets while using Volley and Gson? If not what workaround could I do?. Thanks.

This is my model by the way.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Laptop {
    @SerializedName("z36_rec_key")
    public String barcode;

    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;

    @SerializedName("z36_due_date")
    public int due_date;

    public Notebook() {
    }
}
```

**Update**: 
I went with Jaswant Singh suggestion and just added a JSONArray into my request function.

```
jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
posts = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(jsonArray.get(0).toString(), ItemObject[].class));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bracket represents a json array

You can remove those brackets from server side just by sending the 0th element of the final response.

Or If you don’t have access to that, just access the 0th element (object) from the client side (app or website) and that will work just fine.

If using a POJO

```
object.get(0)
```

If using a json array

```
jsonArray.get(0)
```

I’ll recommend you to simply use a JSONArray to parse your response. Get the response as a string and :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible to be deserialized as an array containing one array like:

```
Laptop[][] laptops = new Gson().fromJson(getPackageResourceReader(YOUR_JSON),
                                             Laptop[][].class);
```

and you could get the results in this case -for example - like:

```
Laptop lt1 = laptops[0][0];
Laptop lt2 = laptops[0][1];
```